# Visual Studio 2019 publish.xml script not recreating all procedures after db Drop

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2019, generate-scripts

I and a coworker are having this issue intermittently in VS 2019, where the publish.xml script that publishes DB changes is not publishing all the stored procedures it is supposed to.

The stored procedures that are missing do not get added to the SQL script generated by the publishing process.

The issue seems to resolve itself on its own, after removing code changes, and several iterations of dropping the related DB, restarting the computer, and rebuilding the solution fully. It could possibly be related to low hardware resources, as Our work computers are very underpowered, (operating at 80+% ram usage after opening all our dev tools)

Has anyone had this experience and/or know how to prevent it?